# Express json() creates strange JSON (key merged with value)

Tags: javascript, json, express, stringify

I'm using express.js to send back a json result

```
res.status(200).json(result);
```

But it seems like the result JSON string contains strange characters.
When I put it in VIM I get the following:

[image]

How can I avoid them? The problem is the JSON.parse returns a very strange result.

Comment: How can you be sure that those are not already in your `result` object?

Comment: [right-to-left mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm)?

Comment: Inspect "result" before you pass back the result. You'll likely find that Unicode character in there.

Comment: Thanks! You're right it was an SQL query that had those strange characters that carry on as object keys and then to the JSON

Answer (score 1):

> The issue was that the data came from an SQL query, which was where the strange characters originated. The characters came in as object keys and then resulted in the JSON.

From the OP's comment.